Is there a way to force the install of an iPhone app on your Mac?
There is an app which I have on my phone for communicating with my child's "smartwatch" (a GizmoWatch). This watch works on the cellular network and does text messaging, but presumably via data and not SMS. As such, text messaging isn't picked up by iMessage.
I would like to run it on my Sonoma Mac (Apple Silicon) so that I don't have to fuss with my phone to respond to simple text messages. I've found that there are a number of iOS apps that I can install and run on my Mac with varying degrees of success, so I'm prepared for it simply to not work. However, I've found that it outright does NOT appear on the macOS App Store unless I go directly to it's page via a link, but then the "Install" button is grayed out.
I'm somewhat expecting that one of the restrictions is that it has to be on an iPhone because it has to be directly on the provider's cellular network, but I'm curious to just give it a try anyway.
Is there a way to force the install of this application via the App Store?

If the developer of the app does not permit the application to be installed, then no.

It's also true that not every API on iOS is available on macOS; so some things might actually not work, even if you can get them to work, if you see what I mean.

I am somewhat expecting things to crash or not work, to be honest. It is more the idea of "it wouldn't hurt to try" seeing how there are apps I can install which are not validated for macOS and sort-of-work. So looking for the "I understand the risks, just try installing it anyway" feature if it exists!
